# RestTemplate.getForEntity will remove file extension?

Tags: java, spring-boot, resttemplate

Hi I am writing an application which enables user to upload a file then later download it. What I found is that the file extension will be removed from restTemplate.getForEntity thus RequestMapping will not get full file name. Can anybody confirm this is correct and how to overcome this?

Controller:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/uploaded/{filename}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public ResponseEntity<Resource> getUploaded(@PathVariable String filename) {
    logger.debug("getUploaded filename=" + filename);

    Resource file = storageService.loadAsResource(filename + ".png");

    return ResponseEntity.ok().body(file);
}
```

Unit Testing:

```
    System.err.println("imageUpload = " + imageUpload);
    ResponseEntity<Resource> responseResource = this.restTemplate.getForEntity("/uploaded/" + imageUpload, Resource.class);
    assertNotNull(responseResource);
    System.err.println("responseResource = " + responseResource.toString());
    assertEquals(HttpStatus.FOUND, responseResource.getStatusCode());
    assertEquals(resource, responseResource.getBody());
```

Logging show:

```
imageUpload = favicon1.png
getUploaded filename=favicon1
responseResource = <200 OK,Byte array resource [resource loaded from byte array],{Content-Type=[image/png], Content-Length=[8971], Date=[Mon, 02 Oct 2017 01:58:39 GMT]}>
```

As you can see, imageUpload is a file name with '.png' extension and is correctly passed to restTemplate.getForEntity() but getUploaded() can only receive filename without extension thus I have to manually add '.png' which is ugly. So I don't know if there is anything wrong with my implementation or how anybody else solve this file extension problem which should be general.

Comment: Try using contentnegotiating resolver. By default if you are passing anything to the url with extension it tries to find a content resolver. http://websystique.com/springmvc/spring-4-mvc-contentnegotiatingviewresolver-example/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Final solution:

```
@Configuration
public class WebMvcConfiguration extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {
    @Override
    public void configurePathMatch(PathMatchConfigurer matcher) {
        matcher.setUseRegisteredSuffixPatternMatch(true);
    }
}
```